# JOLT use value of variable to create imbrications in json

Tags: transformation, jolt

I am trying to give as input a JSON that contains a fixed variable (in my example **group**) that has as value an imbrication of objects and my goal is to transform it to sub objects.

My Input :

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "marc",
    "group": "office.people"
  }
]
```

My Spec :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key).@(1,group)"
      }
    }
   }
]
```

Expected:

```
{
  "name": {
    "office": {
      "people": "marc"
    }
  }
}
```

Actual:

```
{
  "name" : {
    "office.people" : "marc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the group first:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "group": "=split('\\.',@(1,group))"
      }
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key).@(1,group[0]).@(1,group[1])"
      }
    }
   }
]
```